# Samsung Galaxy Tab A stuck at logo

Tags: samsung, tablet, samsung-galaxy-tab

My Samsung Galaxy Tab A stuck at the logo screen.

[image: Frozen Samsung Galaxy Tab A]
All I could find on internet so far were advices to push power button together with  Volume up. 
But it doesn't react for me. 
Push and hold power button also doesn't react.
The only combination where I see a reaction is Power + Volume down after 7 seconds screen is black for a couple of seconds after that the logo screen just comes back and here we are again.

What could be the (any) next step?

Comment: wipe cache from recovery mode, this won't harm your userdata. if you want to factory reset but want to do a backup before, flash twrp recovery from download mode (Heimdall/Odin) https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-t580-galaxy-tab-a-101-2016-wifi/recovery-mode

Comment: I can't come to recovery mode. As I wrote the only combination of buttons the Tab reacts to is power+volume down.

Comment: if the three-button-combination does not work (and home button is not broken) your device is still on. disconnect the battery to make sure it is powered off https://youtu.be/y8HmbYrKsS0

Comment: ... except for the very rare case you have installed a third party device management software which has removed Download mode from your device (Safe Mode)?
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3775903